# Exclude columns and rows with certain values

Tags: r

How could I exclude columns and rows with certain frequency value (e.g. n<1) from this frequency table (just don't need them to be displayed). 
"x" and "y" are factors.

```
table(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
tab <- table(x, y)
rfreq <- rowSums(tab)/sum(tab)
cfreq <- colSums(tab)/sum(tab)

# exclude all rows containing less than 5% of the data
tab[rfreq >= 0.05, ]

# exclude all columns less than 5%
tab[, cfreq >= 0.05]

# exclude both rows and columns
tab[rfreq >= 0.05, cfreq >= 0.05]
```

Answer (score -2):

See the `exclude` argument.

```
n = 100
set.seed(12345)
x = factor(1:4)[sample(1:3, n, replace=T)]
```

```
> table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4 
32 30 38  0
```

```
> table(x, exclude=4)
x
 1  2  3 
32 30 38
```

Comment: That excludes a specific value of `x`.  The OP wants to exclude a specific _frequency_ of `x`.